# How to ignore non-compilable methods in explicit template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class. Some methods can only be called for certain template parameters, otherwise compilation error occurs. Here, if you call `C<int>{}.vectorMethod()` you get a compilation error that `int` does not have a `.size()` method.

```
template <class T>
struct C
{
    void intMethod()
    {
        cout << T{} + 1 << "\n";
    }
    void vectorMethod()
    {
        cout << T{}.size() << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    C<int> a;
    a.intMethod();
    // a.vectorMethod(); // compilation error

    C<vector<int>> b;
    b.vectorMethod();
}
```

I want to make an explicit instantiation of this template for some frequently used types and still be able to get a compilation error if I try to use a method unsuitable for a certain type. Ideally, I'd like to have the following:

```
// header.h
template <class T>
struct C
{
    void intMethod()
    {
        cout << T{} + 1 << "\n";
    }
    void vectorMethod()
    {
        cout << T{}.size() << "\n";
    }
};

extern template struct C<int>;
extern template struct C<vector<int>>;

// impl.cpp
#include "header.h"
template struct C<int>;
template struct C<vector<int>>;

// main.cpp
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    C<int> a;
    a.intMethod();
    // a.vectorMethod(); // compilation or linker error is desired

    C<vector<int>> b;
    b.vectorMethod();
}
```

The first problem is that explicit instantiation in `impl.cpp` fails to compile since it tries to instantiate all methods of the class. The second is that in `main.cpp` the compiler notes the `extern template` and does not try to compile `C<int>::vectorMethod`; that's why I'm fine with linker error instead of compilation one.

We can use concepts to get rid of the first problem:

```
template <class T>
struct C
{
    void vectorMethod()
    {
        if constexpr (requires { T{}.size(); }) {
            cout << T{}.size() << "\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Now `impl.cpp` compiles, but I can erroneously call `C<int>::vectorMethod()` and it will silently do nothing.

I also tried to use enable_if:

```
template <class T>
struct C
{
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, vector<int>>> vectorMethod()
    {
        cout << T{}.size() << "\n";
    }
};
```

However, `template class C<int>` also fails to compile in this case.

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to?

Comment: Is C++20 available?

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure about all features, but `requires` is definitely fine. We use clang12.

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, vector<int>>>` is a hard error, you would need `template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, vector<int>>, int> = 0> void vectorMethod();`, but then explicit instantiation loses lot of sense...

Answer (score 3):

With c++20 `requires`, you might do

```
template <class T>
struct C
{
    void intMethod() requires(requires {T{} + 1;})
    {
        std::cout << T{} + 1 << "\n";
    }
    void vectorMethod() requires(requires {T{}.size();})
    {
        std::cout << T{}.size() << "\n";
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oM7z9W7jT) (Not sure why clang still fails).

Comment: I missed this use of `requires` somehow. I'll check if it works in our case and accept the answer.

Comment: Another possibility: `void intMethod() requires(std::is_same_v<T, int>)` or any condition/concept.